# Smallest Footprint Source Only (No Sink) Buffer Solution

Tags: component-selection, source, high-impedance

I'm currently in the process of designing a cable snake cable tester for recording studios that involves testing for connectivity between a large number of inputs. This involves using a microcontroller + shift register to toggle between a large number of output pins, and testing to see if the voltage from this is present on the input pins. This works well, except that in the case that a large number of pins are shorted, in which case the output resistors between the high and low pins act as a voltage divider and lead to false readings / undetected connections.

For this purpose I need some kind of buffer that will source current, but not sink it. Basically I need the outputs to source voltage when logic high, and be in a neutral high impedance state when logic low. I'm thinking if worse comes to worse I can do this with a BJT transistor array and a resistor array, but I'd prefer to find a single IC solution as this project already has an extremely large footprint. Basically something like the reverse version of the ULN2803 Darlington transistor arrays, that can source current rather than sinking it. Can y'all recommend anything I should check out for this application?

Comment: "*...  to toggle between a large number of output pins ...*" doesn't make sense. A toggle generally only has two options. Do you mean "to individually toggle each of a large number of output pins"? Can you [edit] that?

Comment: @Transistor Yo check out this toggle with more than two positions: https://www.warmanguitars.co.uk/product/dpdt-3-position-on-on-on-mini-toggle-guitar-switch/

Comment: @Transistor toggle has a commonly accepted colloquial meaning that just means 'to switch'. I think it's clear enough what's going on lol

Comment: **toggle** *verb*
1.
COMPUTING
switch from one effect, feature, or state to another by using a toggle.
"the play/pause button toggles between those functions". (Definitions from Oxford Languages.) I don't understand why you wouldn't make your question clear. I know *you* understand what you mean. Make it easy for your readers.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the problem by turning your pulldown resistors into pullup resistors, then you can use a sink-only buffer: the good old UNL2*03 or even better a [shift register with open drain outputs](https://www.nexperia.com/products/analog-logic-ics/i-o-expansion-logic/shift-registers/NPIC6C595D.html), or I2C IO expanders if you like I2C. Note [some of these support making the pins in/out/HiZ](https://www.onsemi.com/products/standard-logic/i-o-expanders/pca9535e) so that would also answer your original question, to source current set the pin to output "1" and to not source (or sink) anything, set to input.

Another option would be to use a micro as many IOs as you have pins in your cable, then you can control the sink/source/hiZ status of each pin independently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the easy way to do this would be to use tri-state output buffers with weak pull-downs on the inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3MHdf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Cable 1 is being tested with a logic '1' on the output. All other outputs are tri-stated so they don't load the test output.*

With a 5 V output the load presented by each pull-down would be 0.5 mA. Most GPIOs will happily provide 20 mA so that could drive up to 40 shorted pins.